# How to use apply and function to create multiple datatables

Tags: r

I am using apply for the first time. I want to count the number of occourences of values in my dataset. I have 10 variables/columns.

This works:

```
apply(data, 2, function(x) {count(x)}
```

However instead of getting the results prointed in the console window, I want to print the result of the apply function of each column in separate datatables something like this:

```
apply(data, 2, function(x) data_x<-{count(x)}
```

It is not working unfortunately.

Comment: can you give an example of your data...

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Comment: The thing with the `apply` family of functions is that `*apply` functions have no side effects in terms of `global assignment`. If you really want to assign the outcome of `count(x)` to something globally, then you may want to do: `apply(data, 2, function(x) {data_x<<-count(x)}`. Just keep in mind that `data_x` gets overwritten at every iteration.

Comment: You may want to move *data_x* outside the apply: `data_x <- apply(data, 2, function(x) {count(x)})` but this returns a vector/list not data frame/matrix.

Comment: I moved it data_x outside and improved my lapply skills. I have never worked with the apply family.